# How can I keep an object that was returned from an already disposed of DataContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datacontext, dispose

**Get User Action**

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    User u = UserCore.GetUser(id);

    if (u == null)
        return Content("user not found", "text/plain");

    return new XmlResult(u);
}
```

**UserCore.GetUser**

```
public static User GetUser(int UserID)
{
    using (PanamaDataContext db = new PanamaDataContext())
    {
        return (from u in db.Users where u.UserID == UserID select u).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**The Route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetUser",
    "user/{id}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" }
);
```

**And finally the test URLs**

***/user/9000*** returns "user not found" as expected (does not exist currently)

***/user/75*** (actually exists in the DB) however returns:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed
>   after Dispose.'.
>
> [ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object
>   name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.]
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(Type type) +1020550
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetDataMemberQuery(MetaDataMember
>   member, Expression[] keyValues) +120
>   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery(Object[]
>   keyValues) +258
>
>   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object instance) +928
>   System.Data.Linq.DeferredSource.GetEnumerator() +53
>   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load() +112
>
>   System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.get_Count() +9
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterUser.Write14_User(String
>   n, String ns, User o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType) +5060
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterUser.Write15_User(Object
>   o) +144
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML
>   document.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id) +646
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces) +72
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o) +10 ...

I'm assuming this is because the referenced object no longer exists but what can I do? Somehow *copy* the object that is returned from the DataContext?

Either way it should be returning XML and not that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use view models. Basically you should construct a view model inside the lifetime of the DataContext and pass this view model to the view result (in your case the XmlResult). This view model should be constructed by mapping properties of the actual domain model returned by your datacontext and all this should happen inside this context lifetime. Ayende Rahien has a great [series of blog posts](http://ayende.com/blog/4807/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-case-for-the-view-model) about view models (It's for NHibernate but the problem of disposed context is exactly the same as with EF data datacontexts).

Comment: I hate to do this but since you appear to be an MVC GOD can you take a quick look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694921/what-would-cause-this-custom-xml-modelbinder-to-not-deserialize-my-xml-post?

Answer (score 0):

You need to eagerly include the child rows using the `Include()` method.