# How can I deserialize and model bind XML that contains multiple objects to a collection of such objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, xml-deserialization

Currently I have a custom Model Binder and Model Binder Provider that detects "text/xml", deserializes it using MvcContrib ([here is the code/setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694921/what-would-cause-this-custom-xml-modelbinder-to-not-deserialize-my-xml-post)), and binds it to a custom Model that I have, for example:

```
<User>
<name></name><role></role>
</User>
```

will bind to a `new User()` that has `User.name, user.role` (just as you would expect), and the Action of course starts like this:

```
ActionResult CreateUser(User u) {
```

Now I am wondering if I can deserialize XML that looks like this:

```
<Users> 
<User><name></name><role></role></User> 
<User>...</User>
<User>...</User> 
<Users>
```

And bind it to an Action like this:

```
ActionResult CreateUsers(List<User> u) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your model binder like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<User>), new SimpleUserBinder());
```

**Note:** You won't need the ModelBinderProvider because when you specify the `List<User>` in your Action it will automatically match the type and call the SimpleUserBinder.

Comment: How does it know what <TagName> to look for as the root element? Should it be <List></List> or something similar?